# SASS Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, sass, visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting

I have the problem width Highlighting SASS syntax in Visual Studio 2017.

I installed extension [Web Essentials 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017) width [Syntax Highlighting Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SyntaxHighlightingPack), but as I understand they support only scss syntax, and I got a just plain text with some URLs highlighting.
Maybe there are some other extensions?